# Как заставить героя двигаться в нужном направлении?

Tags: java, swing

Пишу небольшой 2D шутер, на данный момент герой поворачивается в ту сторону куда смотрит мышь, не могу понять как сделать так чтобы он двигался в том направлении.
То есть когда я нажимаю "W" то он должен идти именно в ту сторону, в которую смотрит мышь (во все стороны должен ходить с одинаковой скоростью).
Вот код:

```
public class ImageFollowingMousePanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

private final BufferedImage image;
private Image scaled;
private Point imagePosition = new Point(800,400);
private double imageAngleRad = 0;

public ImageFollowingMousePanel(JFrame frame) {
    setBackground(Color.gray);
    BufferedImage i = null;
    try {
        i = ImageIO.read(new File("qwe.png"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    image = i;

     scaled = image.getScaledInstance(156,103,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                move();
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
    super.paintComponent(gr);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
    g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

    int cx = GameMenu.BLOCK_WEIGHT/ 2;
    int cy = GameMenu.BLOCK_HIEGHT / 2;
    AffineTransform oldAT = g.getTransform();
    g.translate(cx+imagePosition.x, cy+imagePosition.y);
    g.rotate(imageAngleRad);
    g.translate(-cx, -cy);
    g.drawImage(scaled, 0, 0, null);
    g.setTransform(oldAT);
}

public void move(){
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    double dx = e.getX() - imagePosition.getX();
    double dy = e.getY() - imagePosition.getY();
    imageAngleRad = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    repaint();
}
```

Кто может помочь откликнитесь пожалуйста, большое спасибо!

Comment: А куда смотрит мышь, как это определить?

Comment: в переопределённом методе mouseMoved ,

Comment: А как двигается mouse moved - передом или задом, или он клуглый?

Comment: Сейчас не понял

Answer (score 1):

Пускай за один шаг мы проходим **c** расстояние. Когда мы будем двигаться в какую-то сторону, то образуется треугольник с гипотенузой **c** и двумя катетами **dX** и **dY**, которые представляют собой смещение по двум координатам. Угол у основания этого треугольника и центра кооридинат нам известен, значит осталось найти  катеты по гипотенузе и одному углу.

```
dX = sin(L)*c
dY = cos(L)*c
```

Если известен угол не к оси Ox, а к оси Oy, то достаточно поменять местами

```
dX = cos(L)*c
dY = sin(L)*c
```

Стоит избегать целочисленных координат, либо хранить еще вещественные коориднаты, а потом преобразовывать в целочисленные, иначе из-за округления может случится ситуация, что либо ничего не меняется, либо меняется, но не так как хочется. Пробуйте